# How do deactivate plymouth boot screen?

Tags: boot, plymouth

Lately, booting Ubuntu on my desktop has become seriously slow. We're talking two minutes. It used to take 10-20 seconds. Because of plymouth, I can't see what's going on. I would like to deactivate it, but not really uninstall it. What's the quickest way to do that? I'm using Precise, but I suspect a solution for 11.10 would work just as well.

Comment: Did you try: sudo update-initramfs

Comment: Try disabling Plymouth during grub boot. It may not have converted properly. See: https://askubuntu.com/q/98566/307523

Comment: For the curious, what had happened was that I was running VM images on a btrfs filsystem, which slowed it down enormously.

Answer (score 21):

Easiest quick fix is to edit the grub line as you boot.

Hold down the shift key so you see the menu. Hit the e key to edit

Edit the 'linux' line, remove the 'quiet' and 'splash'

To disable it in the long run

Edit `/etc/default/grub`

Change the line – `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=”quiet splash”` to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""
```

And then update grub

```
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: Removing quiet and splash removes the splash, but I still only have a purple screen with no text. What I want to do, is to see the actual boot messages.

Comment: Interesting, it does not behave that way for me. At any rate, you can disable plymouth with `sudo mv /etc/init/plymouth.conf /etc/init/plymouth.conf.disabled` , move it back when you are done.

Comment: It shows the boot process messages i want to see on a server, sweet!!!

Comment: Plymouth has to be one of the worst UIs I've come across. It uses the same text box for entering a user name as the password. It looks like you are being prompted for a password so you type it and in plain text is your password for the world to see!

Comment: @RyanNerd - So disable it or use an alternate

Comment: @bodhi.zazen This is why I am on this page in the first place is to figure out how to disable Plymouth. If there are better replacements then great. I don't know of any, or how difficult it would be to install a replacement. But my point that for a security login screen Plymouth's UI sucks the big wazoo still stands.

Comment: @RyanNerd - you are posting a comment on an answer that is almost 5 years old to state you think Plymouth is a security risk and you do not like it? LOL

Comment: @bodhi.zazen I guess you have a point. Venting about a UI that has been broken for over 5 years is quite useless. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to see the message for a single boot (vs. a permanent change), you should be able to press the <kbd>ESC</kbd> key to hide the splash screen and reveal the boot console.

Answer (score 0):

How about pressing `CTRL+ALT+F2` for console allowing you to see whats going on.. You can go back to GUI/Plymouth by `CTRL+ALT+F7`.

Don't have my laptop here right now, but IIRC Plymouth has upstart job in `/etc/init`, named plymouth???.conf, renaming that probably achieves what you want too more permanent manner.

Comment: No, there's nothing on the other consoles.

Comment: [Ctrl]+[Alt]+[F2] gave me a black screen with a blinking cursor at the top left, that's all.

Comment: [Ctrl]+[Alt]+[F1] you mean

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to `quiet splash` kernel parameters also`rd.plymouth=0 plymouth.enable=0` kernel parameters can be used.

Either boot and modify parameters in grub console (`c`) or add to `/etc/default/grub`:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="rd.plymouth=0 plymouth.enable=0"
```

And then regenerate grub config:

```
# update-grub
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.10.0-28-amd64
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.10.0-28-amd64
done
```