# Ubuntu 18.04 boots slowly

Tags: 14.04, boot, dual-boot, services, 18.04

after installing Ubuntu 18.04  with minimal installation,
I noticed that it boots slowly
here is the output of `systemd-analyze blame`.

```
     21.048s systemd-journal-flush.service
     19.300s dev-sda7.device
     14.310s plymouth-start.service
     11.883s plymouth-quit-wait.service
     10.579s dev-loop1.device
     10.578s dev-loop0.device
     10.566s dev-loop2.device
     10.566s dev-loop7.device
     10.486s dev-loop3.device
     10.387s dev-loop5.device
     10.352s dev-loop6.device
     10.326s dev-loop8.device
     10.316s dev-loop4.device
     10.288s dev-loop9.device
     10.247s dev-loop10.device
      6.684s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
      5.624s systemd-udevd.service
      5.313s bolt.service
      4.589s snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d26\x2d1604-62.mount
      4.552s snap-gnome\x2dsystem\x2dmonitor-39.mount
      4.536s snap-gnome\x2dsystem\x2dmonitor-36.mount
      4.405s snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d26\x2d1604-59.mount
      4.372s snap-gnome\x2dcalculator-167.mount
      4.350s snap-gnome\x2dcalculator-154.mount
      4.325s snap-gnome\x2dcharacters-86.mount
      4.322s snap-gnome\x2dcharacters-69.mount
      4.111s snapd.service
      3.868s snap-core-4486.mount
      3.452s udisks2.service
      3.405s grub-common.service
      3.163s apport.service
      2.931s networkd-dispatcher.service
      2.689s speech-dispatcher.service
      2.573s networking.service
      2.495s ModemManager.service
      2.493s thermald.service
      2.491s bluetooth.service
      2.478s pppd-dns.service
      2.476s gpu-manager.service
      2.475s rsyslog.service
      2.440s accounts-daemon.service
      2.184s avahi-daemon.service
      2.094s alsa-restore.service
      2.079s systemd-logind.service
      1.881s apparmor.service
      1.786s keyboard-setup.service
      1.740s NetworkManager.service
      1.474s wpa_supplicant.service
      1.110s fwupd.service
      1.097s systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service
       917ms systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-02BB\x2dC6E5.service
       904ms systemd-random-seed.service
       779ms systemd-remount-fs.service
       756ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
       717ms dev-hugepages.mount
       714ms dev-mqueue.mount
       710ms sys-kernel-debug.mount
       616ms systemd-modules-load.service
       573ms systemd-journald.service
       449ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
       426ms systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service
       416ms packagekit.service
       366ms systemd-resolved.service
       323ms snap-gnome\x2dlogs-25.mount
       311ms dns-clean.service
       308ms console-setup.service
       294ms snap-gnome\x2dlogs-31.mount
       275ms ufw.service
       267ms swapfile.swap
       267ms swapfile.swap
       258ms upower.service
       239ms polkit.service
       222ms user@120.service
       220ms gdm.service
       202ms boot-efi.mount
       186ms systemd-timesyncd.service
       168ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
       165ms user@1000.service
       141ms setvtrgb.service
       103ms plymouth-read-write.service
       103ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
       102ms sys-kernel-config.mount
        84ms systemd-update-utmp.service
        71ms colord.service
        65ms systemd-sysctl.service
        54ms kmod-static-nodes.service
        30ms rtkit-daemon.service
        21ms systemd-user-sessions.service
        10ms kerneloops.service
         8ms ureadahead-stop.service
         7ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service
         3ms systemd-rfkill.service
         1ms snapd.socket
```

Comment: I am facing the same issue on Lenovo 320. I have upgraded my laptop.

Comment: So we keep waiting :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have loop devices that are taking forever to mount during boot. Try and see what is mounted as loopback devices by running `mount` after boot.
My bet is that these are snaps (you clearly have `snapd` installed) and in the event that you have no use for snaps, get rid of them by uninstalling them and uninstalling `snapd`. It improved boot time in my case.

dev-sda7.device is your root partition. 19 seconds means that your hard disk is slow to activate, and unless you get you a new hard disk, I don't think this can be fixed.

I know most people wouldn't dream of this let alone try it, but you might want to disable `plymouth` and see if boot time improves in your case.
This will remove the graphical boot screen and replace it with scrolling text.

Disable `plymouth` by editing `/etc/default/grub`.
Find the line GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT and remove "splash" so that the line now reads:

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet video=SVIDEO-1:d"`

[Remember to backup your grub file before modifying it. You might want to read this: [Disable plymouth to improve boot time.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/98566/how-do-deactivate-plymouth-boot-screen?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: thank you for your answer,
but my laptop is new and i tried to test my hard driver and it works fine with 100-120Mb/S to read and almost 100 for writing.
so the problem sure isn't with the hard driver.
I saw the same problem with the same version of my Lenovo ideapad 520 laptop.
so do you think i still need to change the hard driver ?
anyway disabling `plymouth` helped much.